# as in Javascript is not loaded into dom in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a page1.html that has a link in it like this:

```
<a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a>
```

A part `page2.html` is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
</div>
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And also this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
</div>
<div data-role="page">
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

These two `js` files implement some functionality on `page2.html`, but when navigating to `page2.html` via `page1.html`  these two files wont work, but when done with `data-ajax="false"` it works.
What is wrong. Where should the `scripts` be placed? I need default `ajax` for smoother transitions.

Comment: Just place the scripts  in both files

Comment: I dont need file1.js and file2.js in page1.html

Comment: I tried that, it is not working!

Comment: Any Document ready events in js files?

Comment: yes $(document).mobile("pageinit ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

> As per your updated question, you **can't** mix *Single Page Model* with *Multi-Page Model*. When you load *page2.html* first `data-role="page` and ONLY first one is loaded. Anything else is neglected.

### Example:

index.html (first page loaded) - All tags within `<html>` are loaded into DOM whether Ajax is enabled or disabled.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- JS, CSS, etc.. -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- pages -->
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.html - All tags are neglected except for FIRST `data-role="page"` and its' content, when Ajax is **enabled**.

```
<!-- libraries in head are neglected -->
<head>
  <!-- JS, CSS, etc.. -->
</head>
<body>

<!-- ONLY first page is loaded -->
  <div data-role="page">
   <!-- JS -->
  </div>
<!-- next pages are neglected -->
  <div data-role="page">
  </div>
</body>
```

When using *Single Page Model* and Ajax is **enabled**, you have to place JS libraries/code for the *external* page inside `<div data-role="page">`.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <script src="file1.js"></script>
  <script src="file.js"></script>
</div>
```

jQuery Mobile loads *external* pages via Ajax, it loads ONLY first `<div data-role="page">` in `<body` and neglects any other tags out side *page* div.

Comment: @user3283104 inside _page2.html_? check updated answer.

Comment: I might need a bit more help. You are again saying that you have to place file1.js and file2.js in a <div data-role="page"></div>>

Comment: Now I know that scripts have to be placed in <div page="data-role"></div>. But where should you place this div in page2.html

Comment: @user3283104 inside `<body>` tag. Make sure you have one page div in each .html file, because only one will be loaded.

Comment: I tried what you said. I removed everything from page2.html, except for the <div data-role="page">contents inside it</div>.

But now the I get content which was there in page1.html into my page2.html.

Comment: I cant figure this out.

Comment: dont remove `html`, `head`, `body` tags leave them as is. inside `body` add page div, inside page div place your js files for this specific HTML file. @user3283104

Comment: ! Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it! I finally got the hang of it. Now I like Ajax way of injecting and calling. Thanks to you!

Comment: It is midnight 3 AM. And I am so happy that my apps are running so smooth even on low hardware power mobile devices. Thanks to you

Comment: I did accept the answer :). There is one more small problem.
Is there any way of making and external html file display as a popup and not as a dialog.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639877/avoid-page-refresh-after-closing-a-dialog-in-jquery-mobile