# jQuery Mobile doen't load external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using PanZoom.js with jQuery Mobile 1.4.
So I have 2 html pages. 1st one index.html & 2nd one is instruction.html. I have placed two jQuery page on my second html. 1st jQuery page works fine, but the second one doesnt. If I hit refresh, it works find. That means, it's not loading the external script.
What shall I do?

My codes at below:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<html manifest="app.manifest">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>PTM 2013</title>
<link href="resources/css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="resources/css/ptm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="resources/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- JQuery Mobile Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/themes/ryco.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<!-- /JQuery Mobile Theme -->

<!-- apple stuffs -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="resources/icon/icon-144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="resources/icon/icon-76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="resources/icon/icon-120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="resources/icon/icon-152.png">
<!-- /apple stuffs -->

<!-- pinch zoom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/pinchzoom/pinch-zoom-style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
div.pinch-zoom, div.pinch-zoom img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
</style>
<script src="resources/pinchzoom/pinchzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('div.pinch-zoom').each(function () {
                new RTP.PinchZoom($(this), {});
            });
        })
    </script>
<!-- /pinch zoom -->


</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="full-wide">
    <div data-role="page" id="instruction-page"  class="slide">

<!-- Slide Page -->
<script>
$(document).on("pageinit","#instruction-page",function(){
  $("test").on("swiperight",function(){ //put 'div' in 'test'
/*    $("span").text("Swipe detected!");*/
    $.mobile.changePage( "index.html", { transition: "none", changeHash: false });
  });                       
});
</script>
<!-- /Slide Page -->    



      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <h1>INTRODUCTION</h1>
        <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="popupMenu" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext">Menu</a> </div>
      <div data-role="content" >
      <span> </span>
        <div  class="pinch-zoom"> 
        <img src="resources/images/introduction/p-1.jpg"> </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header"> <a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);" data-rel="back"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a> 
        <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
          <h1>&nbsp; </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Popup menu -->
      <div class="ui-popup-container ui-popup-hidden" id="popupMenu-popup">
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" class="ui-popup ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-transition="none" data-position-to="origin" data-dismissible="true">
          <ul data-role="listview">

            <li><a href="Introduction.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/intro-cover.gif">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="Hoses.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/hoses-cover.gif">Hoses</a></li>
            <li><a href="Couplings.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/couplings-cover.gif">Couplings</a></li>

            <li><a href="Adaptors.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/adaptors-cover.gif">Adaptors</a></li>
            <li><a href="Accessories.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/accessories-cover.gif">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="Filters.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/filters-cover.gif">Filters</a></li>
            <li><a href="Technical.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/technical-cover.gif">Technical</a></li>

            <li><a class="ui-icon-info ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-left" href="instruction-app.html">Instruction</a></li> 

            <li><a class="ui-icon-refresh ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-left" href="javascript:refreshPage()">Refresh Page</a></li> 
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /popup menu -->
    </div>
<!-- /Page1 -->




<!-- /Page2================================================================= -->

    <div data-role="page" id="page2"  class="slide">



      <div data-role="header" data-position="">
      <a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <h1>INTRODUCTION</h1>
        <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="popupMenu" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-notext">Menu</a> </div>
      <div data-role="content" >
      <span> </span>


<!-- pinch zoom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/pinchzoom/pinch-zoom-style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
div.pinch-zoom, div.pinch-zoom img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
</style>
<script src="resources/pinchzoom/pinchzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('div.pinch-zoom').each(function () {
                new RTP.PinchZoom($(this), {});
            });
        })
    </script>
<!-- /pinch zoom -->
        <div class="pinch-zoom"> 
        <img src="resources/images/introduction/p-2.jpg"> </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header"> <a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);" data-rel="back"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a> 
        <a href="#page2" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
          <h1>&nbsp; </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Popup menu -->
      <div class="ui-popup-container ui-popup-hidden" id="popupMenu-popup">
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" class="ui-popup ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-transition="none" data-position-to="origin" data-dismissible="true">
          <ul data-role="listview">

            <li><a href="Introduction.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/intro-cover.gif">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="Hoses.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/hoses-cover.gif">Hoses</a></li>
            <li><a href="Couplings.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/couplings-cover.gif">Couplings</a></li>

            <li><a href="Adaptors.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/adaptors-cover.gif">Adaptors</a></li>
            <li><a href="Accessories.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/accessories-cover.gif">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="Filters.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/filters-cover.gif">Filters</a></li>
            <li><a href="Technical.html"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="resources/images/thumblins/technical-cover.gif">Technical</a></li>

            <li><a class="ui-icon-info ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-left" href="instruction-app.html">Instruction</a></li> 

            <li><a class="ui-icon-refresh ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-left" href="javascript:refreshPage()">Refresh Page</a></li> 
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /popup menu -->
    </div>
<!-- /Page1 -->





    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [as in Javascript is not loaded into dom in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625225/as-in-javascript-is-not-loaded-into-dom-in-jquery-mobile). When using _single page model_ each _page div_ should be in a separate HTML file. jQM will load the first page div only and neglects the rest, in each .html file.

Comment: so how shall i do it? I have placed the JS after the
<div data-role="page" id="instruction-page"  class="slide">
Still not working!

Comment: each `data-role=page` should be in a separate HTML file. You cant have more than one page in one HTML file.

Comment: hi Omar, now I am using one `data-role=page` in one HTML file. But still I need to use `data-rel="external" data-ajax="false"` to work my other pages.
So, external code linked like:
'<div data-role="page" id="instruction-page"  class="slide">
<script src="resources/js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="resources/css/ptm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'
But it seems only index.html load the actions & other dont! :(