# Script and Style in header not running in second file

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I using jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and when i create some file like

page1.html

page2.html

The first loaded is `page1.html` like `example/page1.html` and when i click some link in page1 then `page2.html` is loaded like `example/page2.html`

But script and style in page2 is not running it only run if i access directly on url (or refresh)

i found 2 way like
- put all script/style in file and call them in first page and other page
- put custom script inside div tag in custom page

what is the best way i can do? thanks.

## Update

i made example like

[image]

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page1</li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">test</li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /*not running except access directly this page or refresh*/
        .ui-listview{
            margin-top: 0px !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myclick').on("touchstart click", function(){
            alert('not running except access directly this page or refresh');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page2</li>
            <li><a href="#" id = "myclick">Page1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the code. We are not the NSA.

Comment: how do you navigate to other pages? please post your markup/code.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen and Omar please see my update

Comment: place JS in _page2.html_ inside `data-role="page"` div. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21625844/1771795

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is, indeed, having a separate file file where you load the top side of your HTML structure. Beginning with doctype and mostly end the file with either  or starting your  tag in the file.

This file can be called on all your other pages and adding a script or stylesheet only requires you to edit one file.