# Jquery mobile not rendering all 'data-role="pages"' present in an html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an html file in my WEB-INF folder which can only be accessed by a servlet. Here is how my servlet forwards the request to that html page

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/file.html");
rd.forward(req, resp);
```

My file.html has 2 data-role="page" but only the 1st data-role="page" is being rendered. Do you guys have any idea as to why only 1 of the 2 pages is being rendered by jquery-mobile. Here is a template of my file.html.

```
<div data-role="page" id="profile-page" data-dialog="true">
...
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="main-page">
...
</div>
```

So basically my servlet forwards the user to the file.html, could that be one of the reasons why the page is not being created.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by not rendered? Do you mean that you cannot access page 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [as in Javascript is not loaded into dom in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625225/as-in-javascript-is-not-loaded-into-dom-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: @omar I think the link you suggested is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery Mobile we can show only one page at a time, as each page occupies full visible height.

There is multipage template option available, but even there we can show only one page at a time, but we can link to other pages with help of navigation.

The sample code for multipage template from jQuery Docs

```
<body>

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>
        <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

[multipage demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/pages/)

**NOTE:**

> What you are trying to do is not possible with multiple pages. You
>   have to use single page and show/hide the specific divs as per your
>   requirement. You have to write your own logic, jQuery Mobile can't help in this scenario.

**Reference:**

[jquery mobile official reference](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/pages-multi-page/index.html)

Comment: I got your point, I am aware of the multipage template and I am using that, I believe my problem is that I have a single page template from which I am jumping to another multi-page template.